# Alert blocks the page from refreshing, which prevents the canvas element from being drawn

Tags: javascript, canvas, settimeout, alert

In my Hangman game, the Hangman is only displayed at the end of the game. However, I want the canvas element to update after each wrong guessed letter. I have already tried it with a `setTimeout()`, but I don't know if I have put it in the right place.

```
    while (verbleibendeBuchstaben > 0 && anzahlFalschGeraten < anzahlRateVersuche) {
        // Fordere den Spieler zu einem Rateversuch auf
  var rateversuch = prompt("Rate einen Buchstaben oder klicke auf Abbrechen, um das Spiel zu beenden.");
        if (rateversuch === null) { // Spieler hat auf "Abbrechen" geklickt
            break;  // Verlasse die Spielschleife
        }
        else if (rateversuch.length !== 1) {    // Spieler hat mehrere Zeichen eingegeben
            alert("Gib bitte einen einzelnen Buchstaben ein.");
        }
        else {
            // Aktualisiere das Spiel mit dem Rateversuch
            richtigerVersuch=false;
            rateversuch = rateversuch.toUpperCase();
            // Durchlaufe das Ratewort und prüfe auf Treffer
            for (var j = 0; j < wort.length; j++) {
                if (wort[j] === rateversuch && antwortArray[j] === "_") {   // BUG repariert! 2. Bedingung!
                    antwortArray[j] = rateversuch;
                    verbleibendeBuchstaben--;
                    richtigerVersuch = true;
                }
            }
            if (!richtigerVersuch) {
        anzahlFalschGeraten++;
        drawing();
            }
        }
    alert("Aktueller Stand: " + antwortArray.join(" "));
        // Ende der Spielschleife
  }
```

Comment: Ouch... ye don't use `alert()` you can draw text on the canvas

Comment: Sorry, my teacher wants it with alerts.